# I want a join us button on my Joomla website

Tags: button, plugins, joomla, module

I want a join us button on my Joomla website. The button should be displayed on all pages of my Joomla website. Such that upon being clicked it'll open up the job application form. I want to know is there a specific plugin or extension in Joomla which I can use to do this?

Comment: did you do some research on internet before asking ?

Comment: yea i did but found nothing use full thus came here for help

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Custom` module to show (nearly) arbitrary HTML code on your page(s).

Comment: Why is this voted down? `Custom` module exists exactly for this kind of usecase.